# My UWP checking for update not working. Result from GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync() seems incorrect

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying to add update checking to my app following this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/self-install-package-updates#mandatory-package-updates.

However, I found that when I call GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync() on my developer machine, it always return an item. The Microsoft Document sample looks like when there is no update, the returned list is empty which does not consist with what I see. So I tried to compare the version number but the number seem incorrect. (see the code below)
The version number returned is always the same as my manifest setting instead of the version from the Store. (If I lower the manifest version number the returned version number will also change with it so its not the number from the store)

Even if I run an older release build on another PC which is also having a lower version than the Store version, it still could not detect update to be available. Although I could not debug it, I think it is also failed to get the real version number from the store.

Any idea what I did wrong?

```
public async Task<bool> IsUpdateAvailable()
{
    var updates = await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();

    var packageId = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.Id;
    var currentVersion = packageId.Version;

    //var versionString = string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", version.Major, version.Minor, version.Build, version.Revision);
    //Debug.WriteLine("Current Version: " + versionString);

    foreach (var item in updates)
    {
        var onlineVersion = item.Package.Id.Version;

        if (onlineVersion.Major > currentVersion.Major)
            return true;

        if (onlineVersion.Minor > currentVersion.Minor)
            return true;

        if (onlineVersion.Revision > currentVersion.Revision)
            return true;

        if (onlineVersion.Build > currentVersion.Build)
            return true;
    }
#if DEBUG
    Debug.WriteLine("No update is available.");
#endif
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.services.store.storecontext.getappandoptionalstorepackageupdatesasync?view=winrt-20348) works a little bit different from the way you think it works. It doesn't return information of the update package but returns the information of the current package which could be updated. You could check the document description --**Gets the collection of packages for the current app that have updates available for download from the Microsoft Store**.

If you did have an update for your app, then the behavior you got is expected. For example, let's say you have **A package(v1.0.0.1)** installed now, and you have **A package(v1.0.1.1)** for update in the store.
When you calling this method, it returns the **A package(v1.0.0.1)** because this package has available updates. It won't return **A package(v1.0.1.1)**.

Update:

I tried to test this in packaged apps since there are some differences between packaged apps(store downloaded, sideload) and non-packaged apps(debug, running from VS).

This is a simple test so I choose to test with sideload package. I created a new certificate that has the same publisher name as the store. Then I use this new certificate to package the sideload app to make sure the package ID is the same as the store app. This is important because if your package ID is different from the store app, the `StoreContext object` will throw an exception. Also, I checked the app version to make sure it is the same as the latest version in the store.

Then I installed the sideload app and call `GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync Method` to check the update. The method return null. So it works correctly when the app version is the same.

After this, I tried to decrease the version of the app and test again. This time, the method returns that there is an update available.

You could directly create a new package that contains the `GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync Method` and upload it to the store. When the app is able to download, you could get it and test it again.

Comment: I just did a test. The situation is, even if the package version (1.0.26) is the same as the one on MS Store, the code still enter the loop in the sample code. I entered a version number 1.0.27 in the manifest, which is larger than the store version 1.0.26, then it will no enter the for loop. Is this a bug? Isn't there suppose to have no item returned when the version number is the same (up-to-date).

Comment: @Nick Thank you for sharing the new behavior. I made a test and could reproduce this on my side. But I still can't say that is an issue. There used to be a difference between the packaged app and the non-packaged app. So we need another test.

Comment: What do you mean "check the version"? Didn't you just say "It doesn't return information of the update package but returns the information of the current package which could be updated." Which I confirmed is not the version number on the MS Store.

Comment: Check the version means to check the update. Don't mind about that because I've finished the test so I removed the previous comment. Check my update for details.

Comment: I don't know what the situation is but even if the behaviour is different from non-packaged app, this is still a big issue. Imagine developers who follow the code from the documentation. Everytime they debug run their app, it would download and install an update in the background because the returned result always has an update item in it...XD. It is not suppose to happen.

Comment: @Nick It seems that the Store does not consider the dev version as the same version as the the published version. When you package your app, then the method should work correctly.

Comment: I understand what you mean. I just want the point out the issue that after we implemented the update logic, every time we developer press the debug button, the app will download a 20-30mb app in the background because of this different behaviour in non-packaged app. Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: @Nick You can simply add a compile conditional #if DEBUG to check for the DEBUG compile constant (you can control its creation in csproj designer. Put this around your update code so that it only works in release packages.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Why did you use a new certificate in your test described above in Update: text? I have tried your test using same cert and it does not work, i get nothing regardless of version. I am sideloading onto my xbox (devkit activated) which I imagine is why it is not the same. How do I test this for xbox application? thks