# get whether app update is optional or mandatory including version

Tags: c#, uwp

as given here - [reference1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69023081/my-uwp-checking-for-update-not-working-result-from-getappandoptionalstorepackag/69024914#69024914) and [reference2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/209558/how-to-check-new-version-update-available-in-ms-ap.html)

seems that the method storeContext.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync()
doesn't return info about of the update package but info whether current package could be updated.

looking for a way to know whether an app update is optional or mandatory so that can show respective UI
to the user, where user can skip an optional update, also need to show the version of the update available

How can we get this information or is there any other API or alternative option(s) available? and how to test optional update?

So, far tried to check all the properties and methods in
Package.Current, Package.Dependencies, and package info coming from storeContext.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync()

seems Package.Current and storeContext.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync() output the same info.

Also, the IsMandatoryUpdate() method returns true even when the test flight package in Microsoft store is not marked as mandatory (Make this update mandatory checkbox is unchecked)

```
public bool IsMandatoryUpdate() => Updates.Any(u => u.Mandatory);
public bool IsUpdateAvailable() => Updates.Count > 0;
```

and wasn't able to find info about whether update is optional or mandatory and its version, unable to test optional update scenario as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will able to get the latest store package version using the above API as you rightly mentioned it just provide whether the app can be updated but not any information about the version which is residing over there.

To find `Mandatory` updates are there not you can use this piece of code

```
IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> updates =
        await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
    // then something like this 
    if (updates.Any((u => u.Mandatory)) { // some action}
```

Also, to be noted, mandatory updates does not mean something store enforces, its something when you uploaded the app to partner center you can choose to say it's mandatory updates with some enforced time to install.